# MatchCollection giving error C#

Tags: c#, regex, match

I am working with a string and want to capture two substrings between two caracters using MatchCollection and Regex in C#. It is giving some logical error "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: i"
Test String: "A quick #brown fox& jumps over the+ lazy dog";

```
        b2 = "A quick #brown fox& jumps over+ the lazy dog";
        Regex r = new Regex(@"#(.+?)&");
        MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(b2);
        string match1 = (mc[0].Groups[1].Value);

        Regex r1= new Regex(@"$(.+?)+");
        MatchCollection mc1 = r1.Matches(b2);  //giving error at this line
        string match2 = (mc1[0].Groups[1].Value);
        MessageBox.Show("Match1: " + match1 + "... Match2: " + match2);
```

> I want this to print: Match1: brown fox... Match2: brown fox& jumps over

Answer (score 1):

The `$(.+?)+` regex makes no sense since it matches the end of string with `$` and then 1+ chars other than a newline, 1 or more times. That is an example of a regex that does not match any text, same as `$a`.

There is no match, thus `mc1` is empty, hence an exception is thrown when you use `mc1[0]`.

You must have meant

```
@"#([^+]+)\+"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%23(%5b%5e%2b%5d%2b)%5c%2b&i=A+quick+%23brown+fox%26+jumps+over%2b+the+lazy+dog).

*Details*:

- `#` - a hash symbol
- `([^+]+)` - Group 1 capturing 1 or more characters other than `+`
- `\+` - a literal plus symbol.